# Does Weka test results on a separate holdout set with 10CV?

Tags: validation, machine-learning, data-mining, classification, weka

I used 10-fold cross validation in Weka.

I know this usually means that the data is split in 10 parts, 90% training, 10% test and that this is alternated 10 times.

I am wondering on what Weka calculates the resulting AUC. Is it the average of all 10 test sets? Or (and I hope this is true), does it use a holdout test set? I can't seem to find a description of this in the weka book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weka **averages** the test results. And this is a **better** approach then the holdout set, I don't understand why you would hope for such approach. If you hold out the test set (of what size?) your test would not be statisticaly significant, It would only say, that for best chosen parameters on the training data you achieved some score on arbitrary small part of data. The whole point of cross validation (as the evaluation technique) is to use all the data as training and as testing in turns, so the resulting metric is **approximation of the expected value** of the true evaluation measure. If you use the hold out test it **would not converge to expected value** (at least not in a reasonable time) and what is even more important - you would have to choose another constant (how big hold out set and why?) and reduce the number of samples used for training (while cross validation has been developed due to the problem with **to small datasets** for both training and testing).

Comment: The reason I asked is that a reviewer of my paper asked this question and it is not clear to me how weka works. Somebody explained to me how it goes exactly: apparantly, the AUC is the average one of the ten folds. And the model returned is build on the ENTIRE dataset. That answers my question. I was really worried about overfitting otherwise. So I guess the real AUC of the returned model can be expected to be at least as good as the average AUC returned by 10 CV.

Comment: Well yes and no. Remember, that if you use the CV for parameter selection there is no guarantee that "10% bigger" dataset would actually be as good as the smaller ones with the same parameters. It is strongly connected with the fact, that the bigger the sampling - smaller the required regularization. Neverless, the fact is that WEKA computes the AUC in the average fashion, as stated in the answer, and then retrains on the whole data, which is quite natural (as it would be hard to select one of 10 smaller models, and even harder to merge them to one)

Answer (score 0):

I performed cross validation on my own (made my own random folds and created 10 classifiers) and checked the average AUC. I also checked to see if the entire dataset was used to report the AUC (similar as to when Weka outputs a decision tree under 10-fold).

The AUC for the [credit dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Credit+Approval) with a naive Bayes classifier as found by...

1. 10-fold weka = 0.89559
2. 10-fold mine = 0.89509
3. original train = 0.90281

There is a slight discrepancy between my average AUC and Weka's, but this could be from a failure in replicating the folds (although I did try to control the seeds).